# I can't make a function for this button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was making a program in python to calculate the year when you were born, and it was going ok, but when I started making the graphic part it started getting hard and I can't make the button print out the sentence that tells the username the year when they were born.

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime

root = Tk()


def myClick():
    sentence_label=Label(root, text= sentece)

today = datetime.date.today()
name = input("Enter your name: ")


age = Entry(root, width=25, bg="white", fg="black", text= "Enter your age: ")
name = Entry(root, width=25, bg="white", fg="black", text="Enter your name: ")
birthday = Entry(root, width=25, bg="white", fg="black",text="Enter your birthday: ")

age.pack(padx=0, pady=1)
name.pack(padx=2, pady=1)
birthday.pack(padx=2, pady=2) 


age_label = Label(root, text="Enter your age: ")
name_label = Label(root,text="Enter you name: ")
birthday_label = Label(root, text="Enter you birthday in dd/mm: ")

age_label.pack(padx=0, pady=0)
name_label.pack(padx=1, pady=0)
birthday_label.pack(padx=2, pady=0)
myButton = Button(root, text="Click when done")
myButton.pack(padx=3 , pady=3 )

while True:
 try:
    age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    break
 except ValueError:
    print("Invalid age, try again")
while True:
 try:
    birthday = (input("Enter your birthday in dd/mm format: "))
    birthday_day, birthday_month = birthday.split("/")
    birthday_day = int(birthday_day)
    birthday_month = int(birthday_month)
    if birthday_day>31 or birthday_day<1 or birthday_month>12 or birthday_month<1:
        print("Invalid birthday, try again")  
    else:
        break 
 except ValueError:
     print("Invalid birthday, try again")

if birthday_month<today.month and birthday_day<today.day: 
    sentence= print("Hello ", name,"you are ", age, "years old. You were born in ", today.year - age,".")
elif birthday_month == today.month and birthday_day == today.day:
    sentence= print("Happy birthday",name, "you are", age, "years old. You were born in", today.year - age,".")
else:
    sentece=print ("Hello",name,"you are ", age, "years old. You were born in ", today.year - 1 - age)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this is a string. also, what is the issue? you haven't actually said what the difficulty is. from a glance, i see that you are trying to assign to `sentence` with a print, print doesn't return anything so while it will print to screen, `sentence` will be empty

Comment: I never used tkinter before, so i don't understand much. Before I started doing the graphic parts the code was working as i wanted. I wanted to input the age, the name and the birthday and when i pressed the button it would say the "sentence".

Comment: look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm) for how to use a button, look at the example at the bottom it does pretty much what you want, push button and popup a message box

Comment: i already fixed the problem but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing
`sentence = print('bla bla')` ?

Where do you expect it to print ?

You should directly Update value of `sentence_label` without the print statement.

I have never used tkinter but still try this :-

```py
sentence_label.config(text = "your output text here")
```

And you should take age & name values from gui not from console !! Otherwise the gui is useless.

There are so many mistakes in your code. You should use a linter to check all mistakes

Comment: i actually already fixed the problems but thank you anyway.